# Group by to compare

Tags: sql

I have 5 columns in a table

- `importcode`
- `dateoftermination`
- `hiredate`
- `companyid`
- `employeeid`

each employee working in different companies.

For each employee id working in different company id. I need to get the import code of the record which has `dateoftermination` as `null` and `hiredate` as the latest to be compared with other `companyid` of the employee which has same import code to be displayed and others to be ignored.

The above process needs to be done for each employee id. Can you please provide sql query for this.

This is the query i have used

```
select eeceeid,
       max(eecDateOfLastHire) as maxdate,
       eecCOID 
from EmpDetails  
where eecDateOfTermination is null    
group by eeceeid,eecCOID
```

but I am not getting the correct result.

It is Microsoft sql server

Comment: Hi, please provide the query you're trying, your sample data, and what your expected output is.

Comment: @KiranThota . . . "I have four columns".  And then you list five.  I'm already confused.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: This is the query i have used 

select eeceeid,max(eecDateOfLastHire) as maxdate,eecCOID from EmpDetails  where eecDateOfTermination is null    group by eeceeid,eecCOID

 but iam not getting the correct result

Comment: It is Microsoft sql server

Answer (score 0):

You need to use group by either with only companyid or with import code as you want same import code but max hires among all companies

```
    select eeceeid,  
    max(eecDateOfLastHire) as maxDate
    from EmpDetails  
   where eecDateOfTermination is null    
    group by eeceeid
```